# stddef.h(216, 23): typedef redefinition with different types ('unsigned int' vs 'unsigned long long') error

Tags: c, vscode-extensions

I'm starting to code in C and this one ended up showing up. I have no idea what it could be since I didn't change the file that is giving an error (stddef.h).

[image: the error that appears]
[image]
[image: line from stddef.h that gives error]

stddef.h:
`

```
/* Copyright (C) 1989-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

This file is part of GCC.

GCC is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
any later version.

GCC is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

Under Section 7 of GPL version 3, you are granted additional
permissions described in the GCC Runtime Library Exception, version
3.1, as published by the Free Software Foundation.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License and
a copy of the GCC Runtime Library Exception along with this program;
see the files COPYING3 and COPYING.RUNTIME respectively.  If not, see
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

/*
 * ISO C Standard:  7.17  Common definitions  <stddef.h>
 */
#if (!defined(_STDDEF_H) && !defined(_STDDEF_H_) && !defined(_ANSI_STDDEF_H) \
     && !defined(__STDDEF_H__)) \
    || defined(__need_wchar_t) || defined(__need_size_t) \
    || defined(__need_ptrdiff_t) || defined(__need_NULL) \
    || defined(__need_wint_t)

/* Any one of these symbols __need_* means that GNU libc
   wants us just to define one data type.  So don't define
   the symbols that indicate this file's entire job has been done.  */
#if (!defined(__need_wchar_t) && !defined(__need_size_t)    \
     && !defined(__need_ptrdiff_t) && !defined(__need_NULL) \
     && !defined(__need_wint_t))
#define _STDDEF_H
#define _STDDEF_H_
/* snaroff@next.com says the NeXT needs this.  */
#define _ANSI_STDDEF_H
#endif

#ifndef __sys_stdtypes_h
/* This avoids lossage on SunOS but only if stdtypes.h comes first.
   There's no way to win with the other order!  Sun lossage.  */

/* On 4.3bsd-net2, make sure ansi.h is included, so we have
   one less case to deal with in the following.  */
#if defined (__BSD_NET2__) || defined (____386BSD____) || (defined (__FreeBSD__) && (__FreeBSD__ < 5)) || defined(__NetBSD__)
#include <machine/ansi.h>
#endif
/* On FreeBSD 5, machine/ansi.h does not exist anymore... */
#if defined (__FreeBSD__) && (__FreeBSD__ >= 5)
#include <sys/_types.h>
#endif

/* In 4.3bsd-net2, machine/ansi.h defines these symbols, which are
   defined if the corresponding type is *not* defined.
   FreeBSD-2.1 defines _MACHINE_ANSI_H_ instead of _ANSI_H_.
   NetBSD defines _I386_ANSI_H_ and _X86_64_ANSI_H_ instead of _ANSI_H_ */
#if defined(_ANSI_H_) || defined(_MACHINE_ANSI_H_) || defined(_X86_64_ANSI_H_)  || defined(_I386_ANSI_H_)
#if !defined(_SIZE_T_) && !defined(_BSD_SIZE_T_)
#define _SIZE_T
#endif
#if !defined(_PTRDIFF_T_) && !defined(_BSD_PTRDIFF_T_)
#define _PTRDIFF_T
#endif
/* On BSD/386 1.1, at least, machine/ansi.h defines _BSD_WCHAR_T_
   instead of _WCHAR_T_. */
#if !defined(_WCHAR_T_) && !defined(_BSD_WCHAR_T_)
#ifndef _BSD_WCHAR_T_
#define _WCHAR_T
#endif
#endif
/* Undef _FOO_T_ if we are supposed to define foo_t.  */
#if defined (__need_ptrdiff_t) || defined (_STDDEF_H_)
#undef _PTRDIFF_T_
#undef _BSD_PTRDIFF_T_
#endif
#if defined (__need_size_t) || defined (_STDDEF_H_)
#undef _SIZE_T_
#undef _BSD_SIZE_T_
#endif
#if defined (__need_wchar_t) || defined (_STDDEF_H_)
#undef _WCHAR_T_
#undef _BSD_WCHAR_T_
#endif
#endif /* defined(_ANSI_H_) || defined(_MACHINE_ANSI_H_) || defined(_X86_64_ANSI_H_) || defined(_I386_ANSI_H_) */

/* Sequent's header files use _PTRDIFF_T_ in some conflicting way.
   Just ignore it.  */
#if defined (__sequent__) && defined (_PTRDIFF_T_)
#undef _PTRDIFF_T_
#endif

/* On VxWorks, <type/vxTypesBase.h> may have defined macros like
   _TYPE_size_t which will typedef size_t.  fixincludes patched the
   vxTypesBase.h so that this macro is only defined if _GCC_SIZE_T is
   not defined, and so that defining this macro defines _GCC_SIZE_T.
   If we find that the macros are still defined at this point, we must
   invoke them so that the type is defined as expected.  */
#if defined (_TYPE_ptrdiff_t) && (defined (__need_ptrdiff_t) || defined (_STDDEF_H_))
_TYPE_ptrdiff_t;
#undef _TYPE_ptrdiff_t
#endif
#if defined (_TYPE_size_t) && (defined (__need_size_t) || defined (_STDDEF_H_))
_TYPE_size_t;
#undef _TYPE_size_t
#endif
#if defined (_TYPE_wchar_t) && (defined (__need_wchar_t) || defined (_STDDEF_H_))
_TYPE_wchar_t;
#undef _TYPE_wchar_t
#endif

/* In case nobody has defined these types, but we aren't running under
   GCC 2.00, make sure that __PTRDIFF_TYPE__, __SIZE_TYPE__, and
   __WCHAR_TYPE__ have reasonable values.  This can happen if the
   parts of GCC is compiled by an older compiler, that actually
   include gstddef.h, such as collect2.  */

/* Signed type of difference of two pointers.  */

/* Define this type if we are doing the whole job,
   or if we want this type in particular.  */
#if defined (_STDDEF_H) || defined (__need_ptrdiff_t)
#ifndef _PTRDIFF_T  /* in case <sys/types.h> has defined it. */
#ifndef _T_PTRDIFF_
#ifndef _T_PTRDIFF
#ifndef __PTRDIFF_T
#ifndef _PTRDIFF_T_
#ifndef _BSD_PTRDIFF_T_
#ifndef ___int_ptrdiff_t_h
#ifndef _GCC_PTRDIFF_T
#ifndef _PTRDIFF_T_DECLARED /* DragonFly */
#define _PTRDIFF_T
#define _T_PTRDIFF_
#define _T_PTRDIFF
#define __PTRDIFF_T
#define _PTRDIFF_T_
#define _BSD_PTRDIFF_T_
#define ___int_ptrdiff_t_h
#define _GCC_PTRDIFF_T
#define _PTRDIFF_T_DECLARED
#ifndef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__
#define __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ long int
#endif
typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
#endif /* _PTRDIFF_T_DECLARED */
#endif /* _GCC_PTRDIFF_T */
#endif /* ___int_ptrdiff_t_h */
#endif /* _BSD_PTRDIFF_T_ */
#endif /* _PTRDIFF_T_ */
#endif /* __PTRDIFF_T */
#endif /* _T_PTRDIFF */
#endif /* _T_PTRDIFF_ */
#endif /* _PTRDIFF_T */

/* If this symbol has done its job, get rid of it.  */
#undef  __need_ptrdiff_t

#endif /* _STDDEF_H or __need_ptrdiff_t.  */

/* Unsigned type of `sizeof' something.  */

/* Define this type if we are doing the whole job,
   or if we want this type in particular.  */
#if defined (_STDDEF_H) || defined (__need_size_t)
#ifndef __size_t__  /* BeOS */
#ifndef __SIZE_T__  /* Cray Unicos/Mk */
#ifndef _SIZE_T /* in case <sys/types.h> has defined it. */
#ifndef _SYS_SIZE_T_H
#ifndef _T_SIZE_
#ifndef _T_SIZE
#ifndef __SIZE_T
#ifndef _SIZE_T_
#ifndef _BSD_SIZE_T_
#ifndef _SIZE_T_DEFINED_
#ifndef _SIZE_T_DEFINED
#ifndef _BSD_SIZE_T_DEFINED_    /* Darwin */
#ifndef _SIZE_T_DECLARED    /* FreeBSD 5 */
#ifndef ___int_size_t_h
#ifndef _GCC_SIZE_T
#ifndef _SIZET_
#ifndef __size_t
#define __size_t__  /* BeOS */
#define __SIZE_T__  /* Cray Unicos/Mk */
#define _SIZE_T
#define _SYS_SIZE_T_H
#define _T_SIZE_
#define _T_SIZE
#define __SIZE_T
#define _SIZE_T_
#define _BSD_SIZE_T_
#define _SIZE_T_DEFINED_
#define _SIZE_T_DEFINED
#define _BSD_SIZE_T_DEFINED_    /* Darwin */
#define _SIZE_T_DECLARED    /* FreeBSD 5 */
#define ___int_size_t_h
#define _GCC_SIZE_T
#define _SIZET_
#if (defined (__FreeBSD__) && (__FreeBSD__ >= 5)) \
  || defined(__DragonFly__) \
  || defined(__FreeBSD_kernel__)
/* __size_t is a typedef on FreeBSD 5, must not trash it. */
#elif defined (__VMS__)
/* __size_t is also a typedef on VMS.  */
#else
#define __size_t
#endif
#ifndef __SIZE_TYPE__
#define __SIZE_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#endif
#if !(defined (__GNUG__) && defined (size_t))
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;
#ifdef __BEOS__
typedef long ssize_t;
#endif /* __BEOS__ */
#endif /* !(defined (__GNUG__) && defined (size_t)) */
#endif /* __size_t */
#endif /* _SIZET_ */
#endif /* _GCC_SIZE_T */
#endif /* ___int_size_t_h */
#endif /* _SIZE_T_DECLARED */
#endif /* _BSD_SIZE_T_DEFINED_ */
#endif /* _SIZE_T_DEFINED */
#endif /* _SIZE_T_DEFINED_ */
#endif /* _BSD_SIZE_T_ */
#endif /* _SIZE_T_ */
#endif /* __SIZE_T */
#endif /* _T_SIZE */
#endif /* _T_SIZE_ */
#endif /* _SYS_SIZE_T_H */
#endif /* _SIZE_T */
#endif /* __SIZE_T__ */
#endif /* __size_t__ */
#undef  __need_size_t
#endif /* _STDDEF_H or __need_size_t.  */


/* Wide character type.
   Locale-writers should change this as necessary to
   be big enough to hold unique values not between 0 and 127,
   and not (wchar_t) -1, for each defined multibyte character.  */

/* Define this type if we are doing the whole job,
   or if we want this type in particular.  */
#if defined (_STDDEF_H) || defined (__need_wchar_t)
#ifndef __wchar_t__ /* BeOS */
#ifndef __WCHAR_T__ /* Cray Unicos/Mk */
#ifndef _WCHAR_T
#ifndef _T_WCHAR_
#ifndef _T_WCHAR
#ifndef __WCHAR_T
#ifndef _WCHAR_T_
#ifndef _BSD_WCHAR_T_
#ifndef _BSD_WCHAR_T_DEFINED_    /* Darwin */
#ifndef _BSD_RUNE_T_DEFINED_    /* Darwin */
#ifndef _WCHAR_T_DECLARED /* FreeBSD 5 */
#ifndef _WCHAR_T_DEFINED_
#ifndef _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
#ifndef _WCHAR_T_H
#ifndef ___int_wchar_t_h
#ifndef __INT_WCHAR_T_H
#ifndef _GCC_WCHAR_T
#define __wchar_t__ /* BeOS */
#define __WCHAR_T__ /* Cray Unicos/Mk */
#define _WCHAR_T
#define _T_WCHAR_
#define _T_WCHAR
#define __WCHAR_T
#define _WCHAR_T_
#define _BSD_WCHAR_T_
#define _WCHAR_T_DEFINED_
#define _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
#define _WCHAR_T_H
#define ___int_wchar_t_h
#define __INT_WCHAR_T_H
#define _GCC_WCHAR_T
#define _WCHAR_T_DECLARED

/* On BSD/386 1.1, at least, machine/ansi.h defines _BSD_WCHAR_T_
   instead of _WCHAR_T_, and _BSD_RUNE_T_ (which, unlike the other
   symbols in the _FOO_T_ family, stays defined even after its
   corresponding type is defined).  If we define wchar_t, then we
   must undef _WCHAR_T_; for BSD/386 1.1 (and perhaps others), if
   we undef _WCHAR_T_, then we must also define rune_t, since 
   headers like runetype.h assume that if machine/ansi.h is included,
   and _BSD_WCHAR_T_ is not defined, then rune_t is available.
   machine/ansi.h says, "Note that _WCHAR_T_ and _RUNE_T_ must be of
   the same type." */
#ifdef _BSD_WCHAR_T_
#undef _BSD_WCHAR_T_
#ifdef _BSD_RUNE_T_
#if !defined (_ANSI_SOURCE) && !defined (_POSIX_SOURCE)
typedef _BSD_RUNE_T_ rune_t;
#define _BSD_WCHAR_T_DEFINED_
#define _BSD_RUNE_T_DEFINED_    /* Darwin */
#if defined (__FreeBSD__) && (__FreeBSD__ < 5)
/* Why is this file so hard to maintain properly?  In contrast to
   the comment above regarding BSD/386 1.1, on FreeBSD for as long
   as the symbol has existed, _BSD_RUNE_T_ must not stay defined or
   redundant typedefs will occur when stdlib.h is included after this file. */
#undef _BSD_RUNE_T_
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif
/* FreeBSD 5 can't be handled well using "traditional" logic above
   since it no longer defines _BSD_RUNE_T_ yet still desires to export
   rune_t in some cases... */
#if defined (__FreeBSD__) && (__FreeBSD__ >= 5)
#if !defined (_ANSI_SOURCE) && !defined (_POSIX_SOURCE)
#if __BSD_VISIBLE
#ifndef _RUNE_T_DECLARED
typedef __rune_t        rune_t;
#define _RUNE_T_DECLARED
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif

#ifndef __WCHAR_TYPE__
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ int
#endif
#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef __WCHAR_TYPE__ wchar_t;
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif /* _WCHAR_T_DECLARED */
#endif /* _BSD_RUNE_T_DEFINED_ */
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif
#endif /* __WCHAR_T__ */
#endif /* __wchar_t__ */
#undef  __need_wchar_t
#endif /* _STDDEF_H or __need_wchar_t.  */

#if defined (__need_wint_t)
#ifndef _WINT_T
#define _WINT_T

#ifndef __WINT_TYPE__
#define __WINT_TYPE__ unsigned int
#endif
typedef __WINT_TYPE__ wint_t;
#endif
#undef __need_wint_t
#endif

/*  In 4.3bsd-net2, leave these undefined to indicate that size_t, etc.
    are already defined.  */
/*  BSD/OS 3.1 and FreeBSD [23].x require the MACHINE_ANSI_H check here.  */
/*  NetBSD 5 requires the I386_ANSI_H and X86_64_ANSI_H checks here.  */
#if defined(_ANSI_H_) || defined(_MACHINE_ANSI_H_) || defined(_X86_64_ANSI_H_) || defined(_I386_ANSI_H_)
/*  The references to _GCC_PTRDIFF_T_, _GCC_SIZE_T_, and _GCC_WCHAR_T_
    are probably typos and should be removed before 2.8 is released.  */
#ifdef _GCC_PTRDIFF_T_
#undef _PTRDIFF_T_
#undef _BSD_PTRDIFF_T_
#endif
#ifdef _GCC_SIZE_T_
#undef _SIZE_T_
#undef _BSD_SIZE_T_
#endif
#ifdef _GCC_WCHAR_T_
#undef _WCHAR_T_
#undef _BSD_WCHAR_T_
#endif
/*  The following ones are the real ones.  */
#ifdef _GCC_PTRDIFF_T
#undef _PTRDIFF_T_
#undef _BSD_PTRDIFF_T_
#endif
#ifdef _GCC_SIZE_T
#undef _SIZE_T_
#undef _BSD_SIZE_T_
#endif
#ifdef _GCC_WCHAR_T
#undef _WCHAR_T_
#undef _BSD_WCHAR_T_
#endif
#endif /* _ANSI_H_ || _MACHINE_ANSI_H_ || _X86_64_ANSI_H_ || _I386_ANSI_H_ */

#endif /* __sys_stdtypes_h */

/* A null pointer constant.  */

#if defined (_STDDEF_H) || defined (__need_NULL)
#undef NULL     /* in case <stdio.h> has defined it. */
#ifdef __GNUG__
#define NULL __null
#else   /* G++ */
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define NULL ((void *)0)
#else   /* C++ */
#define NULL 0
#endif  /* C++ */
#endif  /* G++ */
#endif  /* NULL not defined and <stddef.h> or need NULL.  */
#undef  __need_NULL

#ifdef _STDDEF_H

/* Offset of member MEMBER in a struct of type TYPE. */
#define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) __builtin_offsetof (TYPE, MEMBER)

#if (defined (__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L) \
  || (defined(__cplusplus) && __cplusplus >= 201103L)
#ifndef _GCC_MAX_ALIGN_T
#define _GCC_MAX_ALIGN_T
/* Type whose alignment is supported in every context and is at least
   as great as that of any standard type not using alignment
   specifiers.  */
typedef struct {
  long long __max_align_ll __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof__(long long))));
  long double __max_align_ld __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof__(long double))));
} max_align_t;
#endif
#endif /* C11 or C++11.  */

#if defined(__cplusplus) && __cplusplus >= 201103L
#ifndef _GXX_NULLPTR_T
#define _GXX_NULLPTR_T
  typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;
#endif
#endif /* C++11.  */

#endif /* _STDDEF_H was defined this time */

#endif /* !_STDDEF_H && !_STDDEF_H_ && !_ANSI_STDDEF_H && !__STDDEF_H__
      || __need_XXX was not defined before */
```

`

I want to use the C/C++ extension because it marks the errors in the code on the fly, but other extensions don't report this error

- The code runs with this error as far as I've tried, but sometimes it gives a preTask error
- I use the C/C++ extension to code
- I already reinstalled vscode (and the extensions), mingw and updated everything that could be updated
- Use other extensions (it worked, but I wanted to continue using the intellisense functionality of the C/C++ extension)

Comment: Are there any `#include` files in your source code before `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: Looks like a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue (in the former, `size_t` is often `unsigned int` and in the latter, it is `unsigned long long`).

Comment: @AndrewHenle no, it doesn't

Comment: @AdrianMole Is there anything I can try to fix this? i don't understand anything about the file because i started programming recently

Comment: Not sure (if I had a firm answer, I would post it as such). But is the problem just with IntelliSense, or does it also occur when you try to compile? If the former only, then perhaps just ignore it ... IntelliSense is neither intelligent nor sensisble.